# How to add client data to SKNode / SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I'm using the `IOS SpriteKit` and wanted to know if there's some way of adding client data to a sprite node?

For example I want to attach specific behaviour to a node, additional properties, relationships to other nodes etc.

I'm reluctant to sub-class `SKNode` as that would appear to break the model/view/controller model where the nodes are just the "view".

Currently I'm keeping a separate hierarchy of controller objects but this feels clunky, and it's not great performance-wise.

What's best practice?

Comment: I have found it best to implement behaviour specific to a node in it's own class. However, if you just want to store information in a node on the basis of which your controller object can make decisions, you can use the userData property.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing won't change anything in that regard. You still retain the full functionality, and break nothing. In fact I think it's almost unavoidable if you are making a large game.

But if you really don't want to then use userData:
[SKNode -> userData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData)

Answer (score 0):

All SKNode classes provide a [`userData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property which can be used for exactly this purpose.

You can write a Objective-C category through which you can add additional properties without needing to subclass. A proven pattern below.

Interface:

```
#import "YourCustomObject.h"

@interface SKNode (customObject)
@property (nonatomic) YourCustomObject* yourCustomObject;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
static NSString* YourCustomObjectUserDataKey = @"YourCustomObjectUserDataKey";

@implementation SKNode (customObject)
-(NSMutableDictionary*) internal_getOrCreateUserData
{
    NSMutableDictionary* userData = self.userData;
    if (userData == nil)
    {
        userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.userData = userData;
    }

    return userData;
}

-(void) setYourCustomObject:(YourCustomObject*)customObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary* userData = [self internal_getOrCreateUserData];
    [userData setObject: customObject forKey:YourCustomObjectUserDataKey];
}

-(YourCustomObject*) yourCustomObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary* userData = [self internal_getOrCreateUserData];
    return (YourCustomObject*)[userData objectForKey:YourCustomObjectUserDataKey];
}
@end
```

Replace `YourCustomObject` with your actual class name.

The category can be extended to host multiple properties of course, you don't have to write a separate category for each property. The category does not have to be on SKNode either, if you need an additional property but only on SKSpriteNode you would make this a category on SKSpriteNode.

Very often you'll need access to the owning node in `YourCustomObject`.

For that reason it's a good idea to provide an initializer and/or property that takes the owning node as input. I prefer readonly properties and a custom initializer because usually you don't want the owner to change throughout the object's lifetime. Very important: this property must be `weak` to not create a retain cycle.

```
@interface YourCustomObject
@property (weak, readonly) SKNode* owningNode;
+(instancetype) customObjectWithOwningNode:(SKNode*)owningNode;
@end

@implementation YourCustomObject
+(instancetype) customObjectWithOwningNode:(SKNode*)owningNode
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithOwningNode:owningNode];
}
-(id) initWithOwningNode:(SKNode*)owningNode
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        _owningNode = owningNode;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

You can then create and assign your custom object within a node class:

```
YourCustomObject* customObject = [YourCustomObject customObjectWithOwningNode:self];
self.yourCustomObject = customObject;
```

Comment: Thanks - that's very helpful. I've ended up sub-classing as a quick solution. I missed the userData when reading up on SKNode!

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers here already mention that you can use the `userData` dictionary for arbitrary key-values, let me add that you're fine subclassing `SKNode`s because SpriteKit is not MVC in the first place (or at least not in the sense of UIKit's way).

`SKNode`s were designed to fit common gaming architectures (*Component Pattern* and friends) and can actually be Models, Views, or Controllers on their own. `SKNode` for example is not a displayable object, but can hold information about game entities/states or other children nodes.